# Firefox: how to serve sourcemaps for web extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, firefox-addon-webextensions, parceljs

I'm developing a webextension based on typescript. For debugging, I need sourcemaps, both in the background and contentscripts.

Currently, I'm using [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to bundle my extension (but I don't think this problem is related to parcel). With the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-web-extension) for webextensions, the bundling process becomes as easy as `parcel build src/manifest.json`.

This also compiles typescript and creates appropriate sourcemaps. I can see the sourcemaps for contentscripts and debug with them. But on the background, the sourcemaps aren't loaded.

Firefox complains:

```
Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: moz-extension://aabd65f9-70d4-43bc-afb8-d04b6eca3602/background.js
Source Map URL: /background.map[Learn More]
```

So it seems to me, as if this was some problem in providing the sourcemap to the browser. I can see that it is created. It is loaded correctly for the contentscript. And I can see that the syntax for the two scripts is identical. Maybe Firefox expects a different way of hosting for the background ?

To reproduce the problem, I have set up this repository: https://github.com/lhk/webextension_typescript_webpack

- `npm install -g parcel-bundler`
- `git clone https://github.com/lhk/webextension_typescript_webpack`
- `git checkout parcel_branch`
- `npm install`
- `parcel build src/manifest.json`

Then load it into Firefox and observe the debug console output. It produces the above error message.

**UPDATE:**
I found this issue: https://github.com/webextension-toolbox/webextension-toolbox/issues/58

Apparently, Firefox can only deal with a specific set of sourcemaps, when working on webextensions. But I don't understand why the sourcemaps work for the contentscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already appended this as an update to my question, but actually I think it is an answer.

There exists an issue describing just this problem on github.
The final comment is still up-to-date: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1194#issuecomment-402494524

The problem is a bug in firefox. A bug report has also already been filed with Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1437937